# No policy found for QueryType - Graphql Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm building a new query in graphql, but when I add it and send the request from my frontend, the error that I get is

```
"No policy found for:\n\n- Type: ApplicantReport\n- Runtime value: `{:requested_participant=>\"eb0b1fda-44ba-4717-94e2-52da818ffdf4\", :report_link=>nil, :error=>false, :message=>\"Works\"}`\n\nPundit error: Pundit::NotDefinedError, unable to find scope `HashPolicy::Scope` for `{:requested_participant=>\"eb0b1fda-44ba-4717-94e2-52da818ffdf4\", :report_link=>nil, :error=>false, :message=>\"Works\"}`\n"
```

My query definition in query_type is

```
field :applicant_report,
      { resolver: Resolvers::Admin::ApplicantReportResolver,
        description: 'Generate PDF for applicant',
        pundit_policy_class: AdminPolicy,
        pundit_role: :any_account_user }
```

My query is

```
class ApplicantReportType < Types::BaseObject
    field :requested_participant, String, null: false
    field :report_link, String, null: true
    field :error, Boolean, null: false
    field :message, String, null: true
  end
```

And my resolver is

```
type [Types::ApplicantReportType], null: false

  argument :participant_id, String, required: true

  def resolve(participant_id:)
    ::AdminServices::Reports::ApplicantPdf.new(participant: participant(participant_id: participant_id),
                                               current_user: context[:current_user]).perform
  end
```

The query I've sending is

```
{"operationName":"getPDFParticipant","variables":{"participantId":"eb0b1fda-44ba-4717-94e2-52da818ffdf4"},"query":"query getPDFParticipant($participantId: String!) {\n  applicantReport(participantId: $participantId) {\n    requestedParticipant\n    reportLink\n    error\n    message\n    __typename\n  }\n}"}
```

Thanks for your help